How to play a midi file with audiokit's MIDIPlayer?
I am trying to play a MIDI file using audiokit's MIDIPlayer. I have the following code:
import SwiftUI
import AudioKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var midi = MIDIWrapper()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {midi.play()}, label: {Text("play")})     
    }
}

class MIDIWrapper: ObservableObject {
    
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var instrument = AppleSampler()
    let player: MIDIPlayer
    
    init() {
        engine.output = instrument
        
        try? engine.start()
        
        player = MIDIPlayer(audioEngine: engine.avEngine, filename: "cdec.mid")
    }
    
    func play() -> () {
        player.play()
    }  
}

When I run this on my iPhone 13 I get the following error:
           AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioSequencer.mm:121:-[AVAudioSequencer(AVAudioSequencer_Player) startAndReturnError:]: (impl->Start()): error -10852
MIDIPlayer.swift:play():121:Could not start the sequencer (MIDIPlayer.swift:play():121)

Could anyone tell me how I can fix this?

The filename should be without extension. The extension is added in the initializer of MIDIPlayer. Thanks to Nick Culbertson from Moby Pixel for pointing this out.
For people looking to play MIDI files with Audiokit, I would also recommend looking at the AppleSequencer class. Code examples can be found in the Audiokit Cookbook.

Try to store your engine first, then start it:
import SwiftUI
import AudioKit
import AVFAudio

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: play, label: {Text("play")})
    }
}

let engine = AudioEngine()
let player = MIDIPlayer(audioEngine: engine.avEngine, filename: "cdec.mid")

func play() -> () {
    try? engine.start()
    player.play()
}

In a next step, you should put the player in it’s own class to avoid the global variables.
For example:
import SwiftUI
import AudioKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var midi = MIDIWrapper()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: midi.play, label: {Text("play")})
    }
}

class MIDIWrapper: ObservableObject {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    let player: MIDIPlayer

    init() {
        player = MIDIPlayer(audioEngine: engine.avEngine, filename: "cdec.mid")
        
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func play() -> () {
        player.play()
    }
}    

 

I just tried this but still get the same error

Added engine.start()

with engine.start() I get the following error:
AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1318:Initialize: (inputNode != nullptr || outputNode != nullptr)]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: inputNode != nullptr || outputNode != nullptr'

Changed to use AudioEngine, AudioKit’s wrapper of AVAudioEngine.

When I replace AVAudioEngine with Audiokit's wrapper AudioEngine I get the error when initializing the MIDIPlayer that the engine is not of type AVAudioEngine.
For the line engine.input = player I get the following errors: "Cannot assign to property: 'input' is a get-only property", "Cannot assign value of type 'MIDIPlayer' to type 'AudioEngine.InputNode?'"

added engine.avEngine

I am still getting the same error: "AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:4635  Can't retrieve source node to play sequence because there is no output node!"

I have added an instrument to the class and assigned this to the output property of the engine. This seems to fix the no output node error. I now however get a new error saying that it could not start the sequencer. (See updated question)
